# Documentation about anonymous users

Tags: support, anonymous, documentation, anonymous-visitors

Where can I find documentation on what anonymous users *are*?

Expect stuff like 'users who did not register', 'users whose username is 'user34894'', 'users who can get reputation points', yadda yadda, but I couldn't locate any documentation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-register

Comment: What do you want to know for "*users whose username is 'user34894'*"?

Comment: @hims056 I want to show the documentation about how it works here to another human being. I can't just go and tell him, 'hi, you know, they name these people user345345 and, I think, authenticate them using cookies...'.

Comment: @hims056: see here (https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Discrimination_against_IP_contributors) as I'd like to urge Wikimedia community to consider doing it the same way you do it, but you appear to lack documentation.

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for.  Anonymous are different from registered users.  People with the display name of userXXXXX are not anonymous (hence they have a name), but may be registered or unregistered.  What are you trying to get at?

Comment: @Bata: see above for context; the page you linked is not to the specific point (although that wasn't as obvious from the original question wording).

Comment: @Svetlana If that is not the specific point and not obvious from your wording can you perhaps edit your question so it becomes obvious what you want?

Comment: You see that I'm confused, I know who I am, but not who user#### is, and not what anonymous user looks like. That's caused by **lack of documentation**. I think.